# Remote controlling Chrome / Chromium browser from Emacs?

Tags: google-chrome, emacs, google-chrome-extension, elisp, chromium

I'm looking for an Emacs (& Chrome) package that makes it possible to
communicate between each application -- especially to remote-control Chrome from Emacs, something similar to `Mozrepl` for FireFox.

I found one package called [skewer-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode) but it relies, from my point of view, on some unnecessary package like `js2-mode`.

So, my question is: is there any lightweight emacs/chrome package that enables emacs -> chrome communication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also the [Mini Kite Mode](https://github.com/tungd/kite-mini.el). It's description contains a rundown of the difference between this package and similar ones:

> Debugging JavaScript in WebKit browser (Chrome) from Emacs is always
>   fun. There's a couple of packages implement that idea already:
>   Skewer, Kite and Wooky with different feature sets. However,
>   due to my specific workflow and needs, they are not suitable, so I
>   decided to wrote this.
>
> - [Skewer](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode0): I don't feel like injecting a custom script or running a web
>     server within Emacs. Moreover, the simple evaluation requires
>     JavaScript to be structured in a specific way and doesn't employ the
>     WebKit Debuger's power, especially live updating scripts. I love this
>     feature a lot since it can be used to redefine closures and event
>     handlers. Browser agnostic is a nice thing to have, but it is not
>     crucial for me.
> - [Kite](https://github.com/jscheid/kite): Is huge and full featured, but I do not need
>     debugging, it is better suited for something like [realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud).
> - [Wooky](https://github.com/katspaugh/wooky.el): sounds
>     perfect for me, except it doesn't support live updating.
> - [SwankJS](https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js):
>     full-featured and browser agnostic, however it is complicated to setup
>     and somewhat unreliable.

There is also [JSS or jsSlime](https://github.com/segv/jss), which is pretty close to Kite in terms of functionality. Here is a rundown between JSS and Kite by the author of JSS, from a [reddit comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1al2ab/jss_javascript_console_debugger_and_network/c8yi0aw):

> i kind of have the feeling that jss is aimed at javascript developers
>   (and i am a javascript developer), the debugger and the
>   uri-source-code mapping where the first things i added; while kite is
>   aimed more at (or just also at) html/css devs (the live updating, the
>   color browser/inspector). having said that, here's a 2 second
>   comparison:
>
> - kite implements much more of the debugger than jss (DOM
>     and Heap viewers, a css color inspecter, just to name a few things)
> - kite implements live editing of js and css, jss does not (and it's not
>     really a priority for me)
> - jss implements the actual js debugger (view
>     stack frames, eval-in-frame, resume frame) which kite, according to
>     its docs, does not.
> - kite is older, so i'd assume it's been used more.
> - kite uses a library (ewoc) for some of the model-view stuff that jss
>     reimplements itself.
> - jss can (and is slowly getting there) work with
>     firefox as well.
> - jss also includes (totally unrelated to the browser)
>     a mode for creating and viewing custom http requests (the http-repl)

Comment: Thanks for laying out different options.  Mini Kite looks even nicer.  Will try it myself.

Comment: I haven't had the try out any of them yet myself. It seems like all of them contains something I'd like, and I think each of them has their own quirks and problems. I'd love to hear about you experiences with Mini Kite!

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in my project [**wooky.el**](https://github.com/katspaugh/wooky.el) – it can eval defuns in the context of a Chrome tab and reload tabs. However, it relies on js2-mode as well (to find defun at point).

The [**Kite**](https://github.com/jscheid/kite) package is a much more powerful Chrome DevTools front-end. It has a debugger, REPL, DOM inspector and more. It's on MELPA, too. This package doesn't depend on js2-mode.

Satisfied?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the answer.  Your wooly.el looks pretty cool - I'll try it when I get back home a bit and if it satisfies my requirements accept the answer :)

Comment: Oh it's `wooky.el`. I think you have a typo, which I inherited as well :p

Comment: personally i would prefer it if it didn't rely on js2-mode and it does look like the dependency can be safely removed, as i think `wooky-eval-region` pretty much covers where js2-mode is required -- like `wooky-start-of-toplevel-form` and `wooky-end-of-toplevel-form` (btw you need `(require 'js2-mode)` in these functions).  heck i can just modify it for my own needs, but i hope to see more improvements coming in to wooky.el :)

Comment: @OTZ, yep, I can totally make js2-mode an optional requirement; please commit back if you modify it that way.

Comment: Can someone give a link for an article on Kite. (Is it working with Chromium 34 now?). Bacause I get errors `Kite: 'Page.canOverrideDeviceMetrics' wasn't found` when run `kite-console`